# SSL certificates updating issue - domain.key .csr .crt and respective ssl.* files

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I am responsible for running friends' website. It's using a free tool, call it T, which did a ton of configuration work for me. nginx config, for example, is managed by T. And same for SSL business, Let's Encrypt certs are managed by it. It has a bunch of cron jobs, including one for updating certs. So I kind of sold my soul to the devil )
And then it all broke.

The cert it offers to the browser is **Not Before** Oct 27 (18), and **Not After** Jan 25 (19). Exploring the config folder - which is managed by T - I've noticed this:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root admin 1887 Oct 27 04:43 <domain>.nginx.conf~
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3247 Oct 27 05:25 <domain>.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1777 Oct 27 05:25 <domain>.csr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2053 Oct 27 05:25 <domain>.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4361 Oct 27 05:33 webalizer.<domain>.conf
-rw-r----- 1 root admin 2030 Nov 17 17:37 <domain>.nginx.conf
-rw-r----- 1 root root  3243 Jan 25 16:34 ssl.<domain>.key
-rw-r----- 1 root root  2248 Jan 25 16:34 ssl.<domain>.crt
-rw-r----- 1 root root  3896 Jan 25 16:34 ssl.<domain>.pem
-rw-r----- 1 root root  1647 Jan 25 16:34 ssl.<domain>.ca
drwxr-x--x 3 root root  4096 Jan 25 16:34 .
-rw-r----- 1 root admin 2036 Jan 25 16:34 <domain>.nginx.ssl.conf
```

T has a script for renewing the SSL certs, which I ran manually when I tried to fix the situation - but it's running on the cron anyway, so obviously that wasn't the problem. But then I noticed the times: ssl..key/pem/crt files are being updated daily; the .* files of same extensions are stuck on the date when now-expired cert was created.

As nginx.conf files all this time were also managed by T, I'm obviously lacking a lot of knowledge here. I see these lines in .nginx.conf:

```
ssl_certificate     /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.credo.press.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.credo.press.key;
```

ok, so it looks like it's using the ones which are updated properly for public/private SSL keys.. but browsers see an expired cert, so something's amiss. Any ideas of what might it be?

Comment: The fact that the certificate files have current time stamps does not necessarily mean their content is good. Check certificate details with `openssl x509 -in example.com.pem -text –noout` and also ensure that the webserver was restarted to activate the new certificate

Comment: I don't even bother yet about correctness of cert files. I have no reasons yet to suspect them. But I do see that every time a "renew certs" cron job executes, the files with renewed timestamps aren't the ones the server presents to the browsers.,, and I want to understand, at least, if the two sets of files are expected to exist, or if it's a side effect of a mismanagement